# Second variable takes the firsts value

Tags: swift, binary, decimal, calculator

I built an binary calculator app, For the numbers I have two variables. previousNumber and numberOnScreen. The idea is to convert the binary numbers to decimals, do the calculation and convert the answer back.

Lets say the first (previousNumber)number I pick is 1010 and the second (numberOnScreen) 10100

```
var numberOnScreen:Int = 0;
var previousNumber:Int = 0;
var doingMath = false
var operation = 0;
var decimal = 0;
var decimal1 = 0;
var binary:String = ""
var binary1:String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func Numbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if doingMath == true
    {
        label.text = String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Int(label.text!)!
        doingMath = false
    }
    else
    {
        label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
        numberOnScreen = Int(label.text!)!
    }
}

@IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 6 && sender.tag != 8
    {
        previousNumber = Int(label.text!)!
        binary = "\(previousNumber)"
        decimal = Int(binary, radix: 2)!
        binary1 = "\(numberOnScreen)"
        decimal1 = Int(binary1, radix: 2)!

        operation = sender.tag
        doingMath = true;
    }
    else if sender.tag == 8
    {
        if operation == 3 //adding
        {
            print(previousNumber, numberOnScreen, decimal, decimal1)
```

It prints [ 1010, 10100, 10, 10 }

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It works for me, check the value of `numberOnScreen`, maybe it's wrong

Comment: It works for me in playground as well but when I insert the numbers though the app, then he gives me the wrong answer. because of this every x+y= x+x     x-y=x-x .    and so on

Comment: Which buttons are connected to `func buttons` and what is the meaning of `sender.tag` `6` and `8`?

Comment: 1 and 0 are connected to func buttons. Tag 6 = Clear and Tag 8 = equals . @vacawama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the <kbd>=</kbd> key, you need to update the calculation of `decimal1`.  Move that code to the place where you are processing <kbd>=</kbd>:

```
@IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 6 && sender.tag != 8
    {
        previousNumber = Int(label.text!)!
        binary = "\(previousNumber)"
        decimal = Int(binary, radix: 2)!

        operation = sender.tag
        doingMath = true;
    }
    else if sender.tag == 8
    {
        binary1 = "\(numberOnScreen)"
        decimal1 = Int(binary1, radix: 2)!

        if operation == 3 //adding
        {
            print(previousNumber, numberOnScreen, decimal, decimal1)
```

---

Also, I recommend that you get rid of the *magic numbers* in your code and replace them with constants.  For your key tags, you could define a struct like this:

```
struct Key {
    static let clear = 6
    static let equals = 8
    static let plus = 3
}
```

and then your code would read:

```
if label.text != "" && sender.tag != Key.clear && sender.tag != Key.equals {
```

which is much clearer.